# Assign the output of a stored procedure to a Column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm executing a master stored procedure to load columns in to a target table.
I have a column called `dptname` - this column is handled by different project team so they have defined a child stored procedure all that will do is it will get an empno and output the `Dptname`. They requested us to call the below stored procedure to load my `dptname` column.

Could you please let me know how can I assign/call this child stored procedure and assign to the `deptname` column in my master stored procedure?

This is the skeleton of the child stored procedure:

```
get_dptname(in_emp_no, out_dptname)
```

My master stored procedure:

```
Create or Replace procedure InsertTargetTable
as
begin
for a in (
Select  EMP.empno
EMP.NAME,
CL.Attendance,
DEPTNAME= "**ASSIGN THE VALUE FROM THE 3rd Party stored procedure**
from EMP, CL
on EMP.empno=CL.empno
) Loop
Insert Into Target Table ( empno, NAME,Attendance, DEPTNAME  ) 
Values (a.empno, a.NAME, a.Attendance, a.DEPTNAME);
ENDLOOP;
COMMIT:
END
```

Comment: Sorry, but you need to provide A LOT more detail.  It is not clear what you are asking.  Show table schemas, procedure declarations, sample data, etc.

Comment: Hello I have updated the Question with updated info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query. Pass the DEPT_NO variable to stored procedure and since it is an OUT parameter you can access value from your master stored procedure.

```
GET_DPTNAME(IN_EMP_NO=>EMP_NO,OUT_DEPT_NO=>DEPT_NO);
```

Comment: Thanks for Your response.
i still didnt get how to use this directly in my MasterStoreProc. Can you please incorporate this in my above MasterStoreProc and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If the other group created a function `GET_DEPT_NAME`, then you could use it as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE InsertTargetTable
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Target_Table ( empno, NAME, Attendance, DEPTNAME  ) 
        SELECT EMP.empno, EMP.NAME, CL.Attendance, GET_DEPT_NAME(EMP.empno)
           FROM EMP, CL
           WHERE EMP.empno = CL.empno;

    COMMIT:

END;
```

A few notes:

1. The data is being de-normalizing: what if the employee changes departments? Your Target_Table won't be updated but will remain fixed at the department set during insert. Perhaps the department should be looked up when the table is actually queried in order to obtain the current department value.
2. Hopefully the stored proc is a function, then it can be used easily as shown in the example above. (If not, ask for a function).
3. Avoid looping if possible. A single "insert into ... select from" statement will be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Glen For your Input.
1.) When i mean here the target table it is actually an intermediary table(Kill and FILL table) using this table i will do and Inert.Updateto the FINAl TABLE.
2.) can't i call the StoreProc the same way as u did?. because the Third party team has only created the StoreProc for me as it is used across many project team. Not sure they can provide me a Funcation.
3.) Yes i ensured that Im not Looping the Insert i ahve updated my Code for Bulk insert.